# Auto detect babel ext sublime

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

Is there a way to auto detect extension on sublime when it sees jsx on files? 
If it sees no jsx then it reverts to default? Currently, I am using babel-sublime
for highlighting syntax on jsx.

Answer (score 7):

Open jsx file,

View -> Syntax -> Open All with Current Extension As -> Babel

Do the same for, say, .js files or .jsx files depending on your project setup, select JavaScript instead of Babel

Comment: But this doesn't apply well to jquery or JS files, if user is working with normal JS files as well.